# Neo4j: Match multiple labels (2 or more)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I would like to do a search, and I would like to start traversing from 2 labels (OR condition). For example, I need to find out all the nodes which have labels either 'Male' or 'Female' and whose property, name =~ '.*ail.*'.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can put this condition in the `WHERE` clause:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE n:Male OR n:Female
RETURN n
```

**EDIT**

As @tbaum points out this performs an `AllNodesScan`. I wrote the answer when labels were fairly new and expected the query planner to eventually implement it with a `NodeByLabelScan` for each label, as it does for the single label case

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE n:Male
RETURN n
```

I still think this is a reasonable expression of the query and that it is reasonable to expect the query planner to implement it with label scans, but as of Neo4j 2.2.3 the query is still implemented with an `AllNodesScan` and a label filter. Here is therefore a more verbose alternative. Since the label disjunction signifies a set union and this union can be expressed in different ways, we can express it in a way that the query planner implements without scanning all nodes, and instead starts with a `NodeByLabelScan` per label.

```
MATCH (n:Male)
WHERE n.name =~ '.ail.'
RETURN n
UNION MATCH (n:Female)
WHERE n.name =~ '.ail.'
RETURN n
```

This means expressing the query once for each label and joining them with an explicit `UNION`. This is not unreasonable, at least for smaller number of labels, but it's not clear to me why the query planners shouldn't be able to infer the same implementation from the simpler query so I have opened a github issue [here](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/5002).

Comment: Is there a shorter way to do this ? For e.g. for relationships you can specify `( n )-[: rel1 | rel2 ]->(m)` where ` | ` indicates `OR`

Comment: No, you cannot use a that pattern for labels and I am not aware of any other pattern that is shorter or that works without a `WHERE` clause. Feel free to submit a feature request at the Neo4j [github repository](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues).

Comment: @Lyman Zerga i also searched at many places but having nothing like that

Comment: I just ran into the same issue and solved it using the MATCH n
WHERE n:Label1 OR n:Label2 approach.  Based on what got returned from running EXPLAIN and PROFILE for my query, it looks like an `AllNodesScan` is not being performed.  In my case, I had two labels, there were two node scans, and the results were unioned.  So, it would seem the first solution is now probably the best one.

Comment: Can somebody confirm @augustearth statement? I'm a novice to neo4j and don't know how to count the number of scans and judge the performance differences

Comment: As an update this no longer performs an AllNodesScan and instead performs two NodeByLabelScan along with a Union and a Distinct

Answer (score 19):

```
MATCH n WHERE n:Label1 OR n:Label2
```

... will result in an AllNodesScan this is a bad Idea!

maybe a better solution:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (n1:Label1)
WITH collect(distinct n1) as c1

OPTIONAL MATCH (n2:Label2) 
WITH collect(distinct n2) + c1 as c2

OPTIONAL MATCH (n3:Label3) 
WITH collect(distinct n3) + c2 as c3

UNWIND c3 as nodes
RETURN count(nodes),labels(nodes)
```

Comment: Why do you need "distinct" at each step?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the `AllNodesScan`, I thought that would have been resolved by now. I have updated my answer, do you have any thoughts about my more verbose alternative using `UNION` and how it compares to your `OPTIONAL MATCH`/`collect()`/`UNWIND`?

Comment: One note: UNION is inconvenient (and in some cases unusable) because currently (2.2) you can't do any processing with the results of the UNION.  For example, you can't use SKIP/LIMIT or COUNT.

Answer (score 11):

With Neo4j 3.4.7 the query planner does a UNION and then a DISTINCT of 2 `NodeByLabelScan`s when you hand it a WHERE query with 2 OR'ed label filters. Trying the [sandbox Offshore Leaks Database](https://neo4j.com/sandbox-v2/) with `EXPLAIN MATCH (o) WHERE o:Officer OR o:Entity RETURN o` yields this planning:

[image: Neo4j query planning]

Answer (score 8):

As for v3.5, we can do:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE (n:User OR n:Admin) AND n.name CONTAINS "ail" RETURN n
```

and get:

```
╒══════════════════╕
│"n"               │
╞══════════════════╡
│{"name":"Abigail"}│
├──────────────────┤
│{"name":"Bailee"} │
└──────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to filter node by multiple labels with OR or IN condition, use this code:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE labels(n) in [['Male'],['Female']]
AND n.name =~ '.ail.'
RETURN n
```

Comment: That works but it makes an AllNodesScan which can perform poorly

Comment: Why use nested list? Why not just `['Male','Female']`?

Answer (score 7):

There is a dedicated way to match on multiple labels now (in 2023).

This will only work on Neo4j 5 and higher.

`MATCH (n:Movie|Person) RETURN n.name AS name, n.title AS title`
[image]

As per the docs found [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/match/#label-expression-match-or-expression).

To solve your specific query:
`MATCH (n:User|Admin) WHERE n.name CONTAINS "ail" RETURN n`

Answer (score 0):

Another option, if you need to work with the combined set or otherwise avoid the UNION:

```
MATCH(m:Male) WHERE m.name=~'.ail.' WITH COLLECT(m) AS male 
MATCH(f:Female) WHERE f.name=~'.ail.' WITH male, COLLECT(f) AS female
UNWIND (male + female) AS person 
RETURN person.name;
```

This is not quite as efficient as the UNION approach, but still avoids the expensive AllNodesScan operator.  In my use case, the query already contains a UNION for a different purpose.

Answer (score -5):

Documentation for v3.0 says this:

> One can also describe a node that has multiple labels:
>
> `(a:User:Admin)-->(b)`

Source: https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#_labels

Comment: The answer is not correct but is not completely bad, I think the author just missed to include the relationship in the query but it works for the purpose of matching multiple node labels:

`MATCH (a:User:Admin)-[r]->(b) return a,r,b`

Comment: FYI. The Source URL changed a little. This is the new one: https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/patterns/#_labels

Comment: Actually, this is wrong, (a:User:Admin) this query describes when a node is a "User and also Admin" No a user OR Admin.