# How to optimize cypher when I want to find a path from a node to another?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to optimize cypher because its too slow to get the result.

My code is :

```
MATCH (e0{name:"dacomitinib"})-[r01]-(e1)-[r12]-(e2)-[r23]-(e3{name:"rucaparib camsylate"})
WHERE (e1:GeneEntity or e1:CompoundEntity or e1:DrugsEntity or e1:DiseaseEntity or e1:ProteinEntity) 
and (e2:GeneEntity or e2:CompoundEntity or e2:DrugsEntity or e2:DiseaseEntity or e2:ProteinEntity) 
RETURN e0.name,r01.confidence,e1.name,r12.confidence,e2.name,r23.confidence,e3.name
```

What should I do?

update one:

The `PROFILE` of my code is

[image]

Cypher version: CYPHER 3.5, planner: COST, runtime: INTERPRETED. 86876729 total db hits in 53454 ms.

Comment: Can you run your query with adding `PROFILE` in the start before `MATCH` and share the expanded query plan?

Comment: Hi,@Raj.I have added the result in the question.

Comment: What is the count of all nodes in your database?

Comment: Hi,@Raj.the count of all nodes is 230,000,and the count of all relationships is 13,000,000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There some ways you can improve the performance of your query.**

**1. Create Index on `name` property:**

Do the same for the other labels as well.

```
CREATE INDEX ON :GeneEntity(name)
```

**2. Use labels when matching (Here for `e0` and `e3`):** Consider using labels for reducing the nodes to scan. If you don't use labels Neo4j will compare all the nodes.

### Solution:

> Your query is internally resulting in an `AllNodesScan`.
>   `AllNodesScan` this is a bad Idea!.

**A better solution could be:**

```
MATCH (e0{name:"dacomitinib"}), (e3{name:"rucaparib camsylate"})
WITH e0, e3 
MATCH (e0)-[r01]-(e1)-[r12]-(e2)-[r23]-(e3) 
WHERE  
    head(labels(e1)) IN ['GeneEntity','CompoundEntity','DrugsEntity','DiseaseEntity','ProteinEntity'] 
    AND 
    head(labels(e2)) IN ['GeneEntity','CompoundEntity','DrugsEntity','DiseaseEntity','ProteinEntity'] 
RETURN e0.name, r01.confidence, e1.name, r12.confidence, e2.name, r23.confidence, e3.name
```

Comment: Hi,@Raj.I try them but nothing helps.What else should I do? ○|￣|_

Comment: Did you create an index for other labels as well?

Comment: Also, there are no relationship directions in your query, can you add these and update the above query?

Comment: Yes,there are 10 indexes on ```name``` in the database since the number of nodes' category is 10.

Comment: I can't do that because I want to find all the relationships between the two nodes.

Comment: I try the query, but the result is the same as before.I think my question is like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20003769/neo4j-match-multiple-labels-2-or-more

Comment: Do you have this neo4j hosted somewhere? or is it on your laptop?

Comment: It's in a cloud server.
```
$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                24
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-23
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    12
```

Comment: how much time does it take without where condition?

Comment: Amazing.It only cost 400ms without ```where``` while it cost 50s with ```where```